# Product as closed form for subsequence of the partial sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

Let $a(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$a(n,m,k)=\prod\limits_{q=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-i-1}\binom{i+j-1}{j}k^{i+j}q^i$$
Let
$$\ell(n,m)=\left\lfloor\log_m n\right\rfloor$$
$$f(n,m)=n-m^{\ell(n,m)}$$
$$T(n,j,m)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m^j}\right\rfloor\operatorname{mod} m$$
$$\operatorname{wt}(n,m)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\ell(n,m)}[T(n,j,m)=1]$$
Here square brackets denote Iverson brackets. Also $T(n,j,m)$ is the $(j+1)$-th digit in the base $m$ representation of $n$ and $\operatorname{wt}(n,m)$ is the number of ones in the base $m$ representation of $n$.

Let $b(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(n,m,k)=k\left((\ell(n,m)-\operatorname{wt}(n,m)+2)b(f(n,m))+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\ell(n,m)}[T(n,j,m)=0]\cdot b(f(n,m)+m^j\cdot[T(n,j,m)=0],m,k)\right), b(0,m,k)=1$$
Here $b(n,2,1)$ is [A329369](https://oeis.org/A329369).

Let $s(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m^n-1}b(j,m,k)$$

I conjecture that for $m\geqslant2$
$$s(n,m,k)=a(n+1,m,k)$$

Is there a way to prove it?